# Iterating through an object returned by Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, python-2.7, loops, beautifulsoup

I'm attempting to create a simple web scraper in Python using BS4, and I've clearly made a rookie mistake.

I'm [working with a URL](http://ny.curbed.com/marketplace/properties) that has twenty `<div>` tags, each of which contains a 4 `<li>` tags I'd like to place into a dictionary, so that the last three values are in a list keyed to the first value. To simplify the code I've chopped it down to grab only the first `<li>`

My issue is that the loop code doesn't appear to iterate through all the `<div>`s found by BS4.

Here's the code in question:

```
soup = make_soup(search_url) #dependent on another function, but works correctly
listings = {} #initialize an empty dictionary 

listings_data = soup.find_all("div", "asset-container")
#If I print 'listings_data' I get a list with all 20 <div>s

for listing in listings_data:
    listings['Address: %s' % soup.find("li", "address").string] = ['foo']

print listings
```

Returns: `{u'Address: 310 Riverside Drive': ['foo']}`

Why do I end up with a dictionary with only one key / value pair?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are overriding the same dictionary key in each iteration. This gives the same key each time:

```
for listing in listings_data:
    listings['Address: %s' % soup.find("li", "address").string]
```

Because `soup.find("li", "address")` is returning the same value. You probably meant to access something on the `listing` object in your for loop. Such as:

```
for listing in listings_data:    
    listings['Address: %s' % listing.find("li", "address").string]
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I'm embarrassed I missed that - clearly I have spent too much time today staring at computer screens.